# Can we encrypt information in google-services.json for firebase?

Tags: android, react-native

google-services.json file is provided by Google when we create a project in firebase to be used in our React-Native Android app. It is used AS IS by firebase plugin. But one of the Penetration testing tool reported it as a vulnerability and the information inside this file should be encrypted. Can anyone suggest how that can be done?